# How to formally show a vector is not in a space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I'm trying to formally prove that a row vector is not in the row space of some given matrix. It is clear by visual inspection that the row cannot be written as a linear combination as the rows of the matrix. But how do I formally prove it? I cannot, of course, go through all possible linear combinations, and I believe a visual argument alone is not satisfactory.

Is there any theorem that would be contradicted by assuming some vector belongs to a row/column space when it doesn't?

I am asking this question for the general case, however the matrix and vector I'm working with, for the purposes of exposition are:

$\underline{\lambda}'=  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
      0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        \end{array} \right)_{1\times(k+1)} \quad \quad X =  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
      \underline{1}_{n1} & \underline{1}_{n1} & \underline{0}_{n1} & \dots & \underline{0}_{n1}\\
\underline{1}_{n2} & \underline{0}_{n2} & \underline{1}_{n2} & \dots & \underline{0}_{n2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
      \underline{1}_{nk} & \underline{0}_{nk} & \underline{0}_{nk} & \dots & \underline{1}_{nk}\\ \\
        \end{array} \right)_{N\times(k+1)}$

In my notation, an underline means a vector and $N=\sum_{i}n_{i}$

Comment: That was a logical mistake on my part. While writing the “edit” statement I was thinking that even if the proposed vector is linearly independent from the matrix’s row vectors, augmenting the matrix would not affect the rank of the matrix which is limited by the number of columns. However, such a situation is impossible to occur, as a full row rank matrix in a k-space covers the entire space, and therefore it would be impossible to find a linearly independent row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want to check whether a vector $b$ is in the column space of a matrix $A$, you are looking for a solution $x$ to the system $Ax=b$. This can be done with a computer (or, if you need to do this by hand, using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)).

(Since your original question is about the rowspace of a matrix, just transpose the matrix before reading my above paragraph.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose it were in the row space. Explicitly write $\lambda'$ as some arbitrary linear combination of the rows, $\lambda' = \sum_j a_j r_j$ where the $r_j$ are the rows. Work with the coordinates to get a contradiction (e.g. the last coordinate is 0, so $a_{k+1} = 0$) and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something that does not depend on examining the entries of the matrix.

Comment: Don't all the proposed methods require examining the entries of the matrix?  I'm not sure how one can proceed without examining the entries.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, notice that each row has a $1$ in a column shared by no other row.

We need a $1$ in column $2$ but if we take any multiple of row 1 we are left with a non-zero value in column one. The only way to remove that $1$ is to add or subtract other rows. But, no matter which row you use, you will be left with a column than cannot be cleared.

Comment: This argument relies on visual inspection and only works for the specific example presented.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\underline{v}'=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & -1\end{bmatrix}$.  Then observe that $X\underline{v}=0$ but that $\underline{\lambda}'\underline{v}\ne0$.  In this case the nullspace of $X$ is one-dimensional and consists of all scalar multiples of $\underline{v}$.

More generally, put $X$ in reduced row-echelon form.  Then read off a basis for the nullspace of $X$. (See note.)  Now if $\underline{\lambda}'\underline{v}\ne0$ for some basis vector $\underline{v}$ of the nullspace, then $\underline{\lambda}'$ is not in the rowspace of $X$.

This method has the advantage that any new vector can be quickly and systematically tested for membership in the rowspace.  Given a vector $\rho'$, compute $\sigma'=\rho'V$, where $V$ is the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors of the nullspace, and check whether $\sigma'=0$.  Clearly you needn't always compute every element of $\sigma'$: as soon as one of the elements is found to be non-zero, the calculation can be aborted.

*Note:* The nullspace will have one basis vector for each free variable: a basis vector is formed by setting the element corresponding to one of the free variables to $1$, elements corresponding to all other free variables to $0$, and reading off (with an extra minus sign) elements corresponding to pivot variables that are needed to make the resulting vector null.  For example, suppose the reduced row-echelon form of $X$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mathbf{\color{red}{2}} & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{\color{blue}{3}}\\
0 & \mathbf{\color{red}{0}} & 1 & 0 & \mathbf{\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}}}\\
0 & \mathbf{\color{red}{0}} & 0 & 1 & \mathbf{\color{blue}{\frac{2}{3}}}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Columns $2$ and $5$ correspond to free variables.  The corresponding null-space vectors are
$$
\begin{aligned}
v'_1&=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\color{red}{-2}} & 1 & \mathbf{\color{red}{0}} & \mathbf{\color{red}{0}} & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
v'_2&=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\color{blue}{-3}} & 0 & \mathbf{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}} & \mathbf{\color{blue}{-\frac{2}{3}}} & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
In your example we take column $1$ to be the one with the free variable, set the corresponding element of $v$ to $1$, and read off that all other elements need to be $-1$.